# Rendering to texture and reading from the same texture does not work correctly

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I created a storage texture and stored the same fragments that is displayed to the screen. But when I read from the same texture in another pipeline's fragment shader it doesn't seem to be working properly...

The Code uses the same render pass and same pipeline layout. I start the render pass and go through the first pipeline then end it and do a vkCmdPipelineBarrier for the storage image texture, then start the same render pass again and do the second pipeline, then end the render pass.

I don't know where I made a mistake?

This is what I was [expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H04Dg.png) but this is what [I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kARD5.png). And its also flickering.

here is the vkCmdPipelineBarrier after the first end render pass and before the second begin render pass call...

```
VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = {};
            imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
            // We won't be changing the layout of the image
            imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
            imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
            imageMemoryBarrier.image = outlineTexture->getTeximage();
            imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
            imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
            imageMemoryBarrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
            imageMemoryBarrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
            vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
                commandBuffer,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT,
                VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                0,
                0, nullptr,
                0, nullptr,
                1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
```

Here is the texture creation process...

```
VkFormatProperties formatProperties;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(creDevice.physical_Device(), VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, &formatProperties);
    // Check if requested image format supports image storage operations
    assert(formatProperties.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT);

    VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo{};
    imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    imageCreateInfo.extent = { (uint32_t)texWidth, (uint32_t)texHeight, 1 };
    imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
    imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    // Image will be sampled in the fragment shader and used as storage target in the compute shader
    imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT;
    imageCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    // If compute and graphics queue family indices differ, we create an image that can be shared between them
    // This can result in worse performance than exclusive sharing mode, but save some synchronization to keep the sample simple
    /*
    std::vector<uint32_t> queueFamilyIndices;
    if (vulkanDevice->queueFamilyIndices.graphics != vulkanDevice->queueFamilyIndices.compute) {
        queueFamilyIndices = {
            vulkanDevice->queueFamilyIndices.graphics,
            vulkanDevice->queueFamilyIndices.compute
        };
        imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;
        imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 2;
        imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueFamilyIndices.data();
    }
    */
    QueueFamilyIndices indices = creDevice.findPhysicalQueueFamilies();
    uint32_t queueFamilyIndices[] = { indices.graphicsFamily, indices.presentFamily };

    if (indices.graphicsFamily != indices.presentFamily) {
        imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;
        imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 2;
        imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueFamilyIndices;
    }
    else {
        imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
        imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;      // Optional
        imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;  // Optional
    }

    //imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;
    //imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 2;
    //imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueFamilyIndices;
    creDevice.createImageWithInfo(imageCreateInfo, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, textureImage, textureImageMemory);
    
    if (auto commandBuffer = creDevice.beginSingleTimeCommands()) {

        VkImageSubresourceRange subresourceRange = {};
        subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

        VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier{};
        imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        imageMemoryBarrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        imageMemoryBarrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
        imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
        imageMemoryBarrier.image = textureImage;
        imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange = subresourceRange;
        imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = 0;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
            commandBuffer,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,
            VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,
            0,
            0, nullptr,
            0, nullptr,
            1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
        creDevice.endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
    }

    // Create sampler
    VkSamplerCreateInfo sampler{};
    sampler.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    sampler.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    sampler.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    sampler.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    sampler.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_BORDER;
    sampler.addressModeV = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.addressModeW = sampler.addressModeU;
    sampler.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxAnisotropy = 1.0f;
    sampler.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_NEVER;
    sampler.minLod = 0.0f;
    sampler.maxLod = creDevice.msaaSamples;
    //sampler.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE;
    if (vkCreateSampler(creDevice.device(), &sampler, nullptr, &textureSampler) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture sampler!");
    };

    // Create image view
    VkImageViewCreateInfo view{};
    view.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    view.image = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    view.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    view.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    view.subresourceRange = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
    view.image = textureImage;

    if (vkCreateImageView(creDevice.device(), &view, nullptr, &textureImageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture image view!");
    }
```

And here is the store to texture shader...

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 screenSize;

layout (set = 0, binding = 2, rgba8) uniform image2D otlImage;
layout (set = 1, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texSampler;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {

outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0) * texture(texSampler, fragTextureCoord);

imageStore(otlImage, ivec2((gl_FragCoord.x + 0.5)/screenSize.x, (gl_FragCoord.y + 0.5)/screenSize.y), outColor);

}
```

And here is the reading from the same texture Part...

```
"""Vertex shader"""
 
#version 450

layout (location = 0) out vec2 outUV;

void main() 
{
    outUV = vec2((gl_VertexIndex << 1) & 2, gl_VertexIndex & 2);
    gl_Position = vec4(outUV * 2.0f + -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

"""Fragment Shader"""

#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec2 outUV;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

layout (set = 0, binding = 2, rgba8) uniform image2D otlImage;

void main() 
{   
    outColor = imageLoad(otlImage, ivec2(outUV)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your image sampling positions. You seem to pass UV coordinates in the 0..1 range from your vertex to your fragment shader and use these for your image loads. But unlike image sampling, image loads expect image coordinates in texel space. So e.g. if your image has a dimension of 512x512 and you want to sample from the center, you'd need to use ivec(256, 256) for your image load.

Comment: That did work.... thank you. But the first render pass rendered the models with VK_CULL_MODE_NONE and when it is stored in swapchain image it works but when storing it in the storage image in same shader it looks like it does some culling and the image is flickering. Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: You need to add some more details if you need help on that. If stuff is flickering, it's most often caused by synchronization issues.

Comment: In the first shader example given by me -> The output given to the swapchain image ""**outColor**"" shows the model with no front or back face culling. But in the same shader (in ""**imagestore()**"" line) the color is stored in STORAGE_IMAGE (I don't know why) is using front or back face culling and not drawing some faces, which I want to resolve. **I'm not good at English so if you don't get what I'm trying to tell please inform me**

Comment: So you use different pipelines for the two passes? If so, it may be as simple as flipping the winding order in your offscreen pass. If in doubt, you an use tools like [RenderDoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) to check state and vertex output state.

Comment: The offscreen is using a single **Quad**. So I'm sure there is no winding problem. As you can see in my first shader example, the **first Pipeline does both storing image to storage image and Swapchain image at the same time**. So, why is the same pipeline stores correctly on the Swapchain image and not for the storage image?